# A question on biharmonic functions

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $w$ be a function $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ with the following properties:

- $w$ is globally $\alpha$-Hölder continuous, $\alpha \in (0,1)$;
- $w$ is biharmonic on $\{w>0\}$;
- $w$ is subharmonic on $\mathbb R^n$;
- $w\geq 0$;
- the set $\{w=0\}$ is not empty.

Question: Is $w\equiv 0$?

I would appreciate proof strategies and useful references.

Comment: TeX note: please typeset sets as, for example, $\{w > 0\}$ `$\{w > 0\}$`, not {$w > 0$} `{$w > 0$}`.  Notice the different shape of the braces and, more importantly, the different spacing.  I have edited accordingly.  (Even better for my tastes is $\{x \in \mathbb R^n \mathrel: w(x) > 0\}$ or, if you don't like dummy variables, $w^{-1}((0, \infty))$, but, inexplicably, the mathematical community does not automatically and universally follow my tastes.)

Comment: You'll find that in sub-areas of PDE dealing with level sets/positivity sets of solutions, the shorthand $\{w > 0\}$ is ubiquitous, and we prefer it because it focuses on the important information ($x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is clear in the context and more than doubles the size of something that will often be e.g. a domain of integration; in $w^{-1}((0, \infty))$ the key information is localized to the second $($, making it clumsy). Obviously in other areas $\{w > 0\}$ will be ambiguous (is it a set of points or set of functions?), and I agree with the rest of the comment.

Comment: Similarly, in probability one usually writes $P(X\in A)$, not (correctly) $P(\{ \omega\in\Omega : X(\omega)\in A\})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $w = (1 - |x|^{2 - n})_+$, with $n > 2$.

This is globally Lipschitz. It is harmonic when positive, so therefore also biharmonic. it is subharmonic everywhere (max of two harmonic functions is subharmonic). It is clearly nonnegative, and $\{w = 0\}$ is nonempty.

Comment: Maybe a naive question: Why not just take $x \mapsto \lvert x \rvert$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and then extend it constantly along the other axes to get an example on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Sure, that also works.

Comment: I guess my thought was: the OP is asking whether a stronger version of the following "Liouville" theorem is true: if $u$ is a nonnegative entire (Lipschitz) subharmonic function, is it constant? This is false with either of our examples. But it is also false if one replaces "nonnegative" with "bounded," using my example, in dimension $n \geq 3$. But it's _true_ in dimension 1. Exercise to any lurking students: what about $n = 2$?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @JochenGlueck: $f(x)=|x|$ is not globally Holder continuous.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Ouch - I really completely ignored that the assumption $\alpha < 1$ becomes an issue due to the word "globally". Thanks!

Comment: @user378654: Thank you.